# Jquery drag and item positon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jqueryui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) I have to drag  elements and also save there position in database so that next time if we load the page it will show based on previous adjustment like if first item is drag on bottom of fifth element then next time it will show below the fifth element on page load.My Question is that how can we get position after drag.Any help should be appreciated.

```
<style>
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
revert: true
});
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
connectToSortable: "#sortable",
helper: "clone",
revert: "invalid"
});
$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/princefiddle/xFaMD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this example and the `updateCounterStatus` function:

```
<style>
  #draggable { width: 16em; padding: 0 1em; }
  #draggable ul li { margin: 1em 0; padding: 0.5em 0; } * html #draggable ul li { height: 1%; }
  #draggable ul li span.ui-icon { float: left; }
  #draggable ul li span.count { font-weight: bold; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var $start_counter = $( "#event-start" ),
      $drag_counter = $( "#event-drag" ),
      $stop_counter = $( "#event-stop" ),
      counts = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      start: function() {
        counts[ 0 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
      },
      drag: function() {
        counts[ 1 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $drag_counter, counts[ 1 ] );
      },
      stop: function() {
        counts[ 2 ]++;
        updateCounterStatus( $stop_counter, counts[ 2 ] );
      }
    });

    function updateCounterStatus( $event_counter, new_count ) {
      // first update the status visually...
      if ( !$event_counter.hasClass( "ui-state-hover" ) ) {
        $event_counter.addClass( "ui-state-hover" )
          .siblings().removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
      }
      // ...then update the numbers
      $( "span.count", $event_counter ).text( new_count );
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">

  <p>Drag me to trigger the chain of events.</p>

  <ul class="ui-helper-reset">
    <li id="event-start" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-play"></span>"start" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
    <li id="event-drag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>"drag" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
    <li id="event-stop" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-stop"></span>"stop" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```